# Sharpe Ratio as loss function in LSTM

Tags: python, deep-learning, lstm, finance, portfolio

I am trying to customize the loss function via passing the Sharpe Ratio, which is the mean of the returns of the financial asset divided by its standard deviation. It is part of a project of mine that tries to use LSTM to do Asset Allocation. I am getting a bit of trouble in here since LSTM uses 3D arrays. Without further due, the code:

```
def sharpe_loss(X_train,y_pred):
    y_pred = tf.Variable(y_pred,dtype=tf.float64)
    port_ret = tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(data,y_pred),axis=1)
    s_ratio = K.mean(port_ret)/K.std(port_ret)
    
    return exp(-s_ratio)
```

I have put the Sharpe ratio as negative since the system will try to minimize it while I want the opposite. Below there is the full extent of the code. Thanks for your help.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import yfinance as yf
import keras.backend as K
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM, Flatten, Dense, BatchNormalization
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error as mae

symbols=['GLD','VYM','AOK','BNDX','QCLN']

data = pd.DataFrame()

for sym in symbols:
    data[sym] = yf.download(sym,period='MAX')['Adj Close']

log_ret = np.log(data/data.shift()).dropna()
log_ret = log_ret.resample('BMS').first().dropna()

covariances = {}

for i in log_ret.index:
    mask = ((log_ret.index.month == i.month) & (log_ret.index.year == i.year))
    covariances[i] = log_ret.loc[mask].cov()

port_ret, port_vol , port_weights = {}, {}, {}

for date in covariances.keys():
    cov = covariances[date]
    for single_portfolio in range(500):
        weights = np.random.random(5)
        weights /= np.sum(weights)
        returns = np.dot(weights, log_ret.loc[date])
        volatility = np.sqrt(np.dot(weights.T,np.dot(cov,weights)))
        port_ret.setdefault(date,[]).append(returns)
        port_vol.setdefault(date,[]).append(volatility)
        port_weights.setdefault(date,[]).append(weights)
        
sharpe_ratio, max_sharpe_idxs = {},{}

for date in port_ret.keys():
    for i, ret in enumerate(port_ret[date]):
        volatility = port_vol[date][i]
        sharpe_ratio.setdefault(date,[]).append(ret/volatility)
        
    max_sharpe_idxs[date] = np.argmax(sharpe_ratio[date])

targets, features = [], []

for date, ret in log_ret.iterrows():
    best_idx = max_sharpe_idxs[date]
    targets.append(port_weights[date][best_idx])
    features.append(ret)

targets = np.array(targets)
features = np.array(features)

look_back = 12
scaler_x = MinMaxScaler()
features = scaler_x.fit_transform(features)
scaler_y = MinMaxScaler()
targets = scaler_y.fit_transform(targets)

def create_dataset(x,y):
    data_x = []
    data_y = []
    
    for i in range(features.shape[0] - look_back):
        x_i = x[i:(i+look_back),:]
        data_x.append(x_i)
        
        y_i = y[(i+look_back),:]
        data_y.append(y_i)
    
    return np.array(data_x),np.array(data_y)

X, y = create_dataset(features,targets)

X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X, y, 
                                                 test_size=0.2,shuffle=False)

callback_list=[EarlyStopping(monitor='val_mae',patience=7)]

def sharpe_loss(X_train,y_pred):
    y_pred = tf.Variable(y_pred,dtype=tf.float64)
    port_ret = tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(data,y_pred),axis=1)
    s_ratio = K.mean(port_ret)/K.std(port_ret)
    
    return exp(-s_ratio)

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(64,activation='relu',return_sequences=True))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(LSTM(32,return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(16,return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dense(5,activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss=sharpe_loss,optimizer='adam',metrics=['mae'])

history = model.fit(X_train,y_train,epochs=100,batch_size=7, 
                    validation_data=(X_test,y_test), callbacks=callback_list)
```

Comment: Can you try to narrow down the specific problem? Maybe only report the part of your code that gives you trouble.

Answer (score 0):

First I see that the variables in your dataframe are float64 and y_pred is float32. Start by transforming your dataframe variables to float32 and keep y_pred in float32 as well. Also by setting run_eagerly to True will help you debug that loop if anything goes wrong. But at a glance, I think you will have incompatible shapes.

For the dataframe :

```
for column in data:
    data[column] = data[column].astype('float32')
```

and in the sharpe loss :

```
y_pred = tf.Variable(y_pred, dtype=tf.float32)
```

Setting run_eagerly to true :

```
model.compile(loss=sharpe_loss,
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['mae'],
              run_eagerly=True)
```